# SSRS - When navigating to a linked website or report, then navigate back, lose scroll position and parameters

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, microsoft-edge

We use many SSRS reports.  Quite a few of them are hyperlinked together.  We have a summary report that has parameters.  The user selects the parameters, hits "View Report" which runs the report, scrolls down to the record they are looking for, clicks on the link.  It takes them to the detail report.  They hit the back button to get back to the original report, and they have lost the scroll position and the parameters.  Is there any way to fix this?

This behavior is in Chrome and Edge.  Surprisingly, IE works fine.

What other information would be helpful?  We are running SSRS 2016.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you say, "hit the back button" do you mean the browsers back button or the "Go back to the Parent Report" button in the report controls toolbar (next to the zoom control) ?

[image]

If you are linking the reports by using a "Go to report" action then the "Back to Parent Report" button should work as you expected, the browser back button will not.

If you  are linking the reports by creating a URL then there is no simple way to do this. The only other option here is to hold Ctrl down when you click the lick to open in a new tab in your browser.

Comment: That is great! It worked!  I thought it was something easy that I was missing.

Comment: Do you know why The "Go back to the Parent Report" button disappears?  It isn't always there.

Comment: It should be there if you used a `Go To Report` action on your main report. If you built a URL to run the subreport then the `back to parent` button will not appear. In this case you have to Ctrl+Click the links to open in a new tab.

Comment: When I'm viewing through SSRS, everything looks and works fine.  But when I view it through the ReportViewer.aspx, the "Go back to Parent Report" button isn't there.  Trying to find out how to turn it on.  Maybe it is a setting somewhere?